# How to know which python is running under ipython?

Tags: python, ipython

I have several versions of python installed on my computer:

```
$ which ipython
/usr/local/share/python/ipython
$ ipython
Python 2.7.3 (default, Nov 28 2012, 13:43:07) 

$ which python
/usr/bin/python
$ python
Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Jun 24 2010, 21:47:49)
```

I would like to locate the python bin running under my ipython.
thanks for your help

Comment: Have you tried `$ head /usr/log/share/python/ipython` to see the hashbang of the ipython 'executable'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
head -n 1 $(which ipython)
```

Answer (score 8):

```
In [1]: import sys

In [2]: sys.version
Out[2]: '2.7.2 |EPD_free 7.2-2 (32-bit)| (default, Sep 14 2011, 11:02:05) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]'

In [3]: sys.executable
Out[3]: 'C:\\Python27\\python2.7.exe'
```